# Cordova how to set correct viewport for all devices

Tags: android, html, cordova, viewport

I have always the problem that all the icons and font are displayed to high on the newer mobiles (Android 5+). I thought about the viewport and how to edit this that everything (every device) looks right.

My actual Viewport now is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
```

What do I have to change to make the design, the look on every device equal. Maybe I also change something else?